# Android Studio: Connection timed out: connect

Tags: android, android-studio

After every new updates of android studio i see new issues that takes lots of time to find a solution for it and sometimes you can't find any good solution to solve the problem forever for example:

**In android studio 3.0 and above 3.1.3 and 3.1.4 there is a problem when you want to build your project is that**

> Android Studio: Gradle sync failed: Connection timed out: connect

I have searched a lot and found lots of solutions and tried all of them but none of them don't solved this problem forever such as updating android sdk, cleaning  build cache,Invalidate Caches/Restart and also other solutions such as adding android studio to firewall whitelist and etc.

I see this problem every day if any body have a solution to solve this problem forever me and maybe other android developers will be happy.
thanks a lot.

**Updated Question with SDK Tools section:**

[image]

Comment: Can you show me a pic of your SDK Tools section window of android studio?

Comment: @UmangBurman i have updated the question with sdk tools section

Comment: Can't see your build tools version.. What version is it?

Comment: @UmangBurman latest build tools version is 28.0.1

Comment: Okay Cool, try my below answer and Restart Android Studio. I hope it will not come now.

Answer (score 0):

### Android Studio

In Android Studio you can make gradle to build your apps fully offline by activating this option:

`Settings` -> `Build, Execution, Deployment` -> `Build tools` -> `Gradle`

[image]

Hope this will help.

Comment: thanks for answer, but i have tested it and don't solve the connection time out problem

Comment: Oh, Are you connected to internet when you start AS?

Comment: Have you logged in? You can find it in Right Top Corner. A small avatar icon. Login with Google and try.

Answer (score 0):

In android studio you can set the http proxy, and then you check connection to www.android.com. If it succeeds, it means the problem is solved.**File**->**setting**->**http proxy**

Answer (score -1):

It seems like a network problem. Maybe your dns cannot resolve gradle repo addresses. I suggest you to change your dns addresses and try again when this problem happened again. Cloudflare + APNIC started a dns service https://1.1.1.1/.